# can pylons + authkit ignore particular responses with 401 status?

Tags: python, http, pylons, authkit

i am writing a pylons app, and I am using authkit for authentication/authorization. if a user is not logged in and hits a page that requires authorization, authkit swallows the 401 (not authenticated) response and redirects to a login page. this is great for the web interface, but not great for our web services. when an unauthenticated user this a protected web service, we'd like to set the status of the response to 401.

is there are way to slip some 401 responses past authkit in pylons, but not all?

thanks,
matt

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [authkit.setup.intercept](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/authkitcookbook/Configuration) option is designed to do precisely this.